# How to ad-hoc snapshots on Debezium

Tags: apache-kafka, snapshot, debezium

I have Debezium in a container, capturing all changes of PostgeSQL database records.

How to delete all kafka topics which are created already and initiate ad-hoc snapshot from the beginning for all tables configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `kafka-topics --delete`, just like any other topic. The Debezium ones typically match your database schema/table name. You'll also need to find the internal offsets topic created by Kafka Connect framework.

For Docker, though, if you restart Kafka and Zookeeper and they don't have volumes attached, then they'll lose everything, which would be easier for ad-hoc development.

Also, you don't need Zookeeper anymore, as of Kafka 3.3.1